# Could not find the lapack library! Could not find a sufficient BLAS/LAPACK installation: BLAS/LAPACK symbol check failed

Tags: c++, cmake, lapack, blas

I have one question when I installed [deal.II](https://github.com/dealii/dealii) (version 9.5.0-pre) during compiling.

I use:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/dealII -DLAPACK_FOUND=true
-DDEAL_II_WITH_UMFPACK=ON -DDEAL_II_WITH_LAPACK=ON -DLAPACK_LIBRARIES="/usr/local/lib64/libblas.a;/usr/local/lib64/liblapack.a" ./..
```

because I need to use UMFPACK. From the CMake error information below it said that the installation of BLAS and LAPACK are not be found.

CMake Error information

```
Include /var/install/dealii/cmake/configure/configure_00_threads.cmake
 -- Looking for pthread.h -- Looking for pthread.h - found
 -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
 -- Check if compiler accepts -pthread -- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
 -- Found Threads: TRUE --
 -- Include /var/install/dealii/cmake/configure/configure_10_lapack.cmake
 -- Looking for Fortran sgemm -- Looking for Fortran sgemm - not found
 -- Looking for Fortran sgemm -- Looking for Fortran sgemm - not found
 -- Looking for Fortran sgemm -- Looking for Fortran sgemm - found
 -- Found BLAS: /usr/local/lib64/libopenblas.a;-pthread
 -- Found LAPACK: /usr/local/lib64/libblas.a;/usr/local/lib64/liblapack.a
 -- Processing LAPACK variables and targets -- Processing LAPACK variables and targets - Done
 -- Performing Test LAPACK_SYMBOL_CHECK -- Performing Test LAPACK_SYMBOL_CHECK - Failed
 -- Could not find a sufficient BLAS/LAPACK installation: BLAS/LAPACK symbol check failed! Consult CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log for further information.
 -- Performing Test MKL_SYMBOL_CHECK -- Performing Test MKL_SYMBOL_CHECK - Failed
 -- Use other than Intel MKL implementation of BLAS/LAPACK (consult CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log for further information).
 -- DEAL_II_WITH_LAPACK has unmet external dependencies. CMake Error at cmake/macros/macro_configure_feature.cmake:112 (message): Could not find the lapack library! Could not find a sufficient BLAS/LAPACK installation: BLAS/LAPACK symbol check failed! This usually means that your BLAS/LAPACK installation is incomplete or the link line is broken. Consult CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log for further information
```

These are what I have installed(lapack and blas) :

````
 1. 
    /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3
    /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3.8
    /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3.8.0
    /usr/lib64/liblapacke.so.3
    /usr/lib64/liblapacke.so.3.8
    /usr/lib64/liblapacke.so.3.8.0
    ```
    and 

2. 
    /usr/lib64/libopenblas.so.0
    /usr/lib64/libopenblasp.so.0
    /usr/lib64/libblas64_.so.3
    /usr/lib64/libblas64_.so.3.8
    /usr/lib64/libblas64_.so.3.8.0
    /usr/lib64/libcblas64_.so.3
    /usr/lib64/libcblas64_.so.3.8
    /usr/lib64/libcblas64_.so.3.8.0
    /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3
    /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3.8
    /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3.8.0
    /usr/lib64/libcblas.so.3
    /usr/lib64/libcblas.so.3.8
    /usr/lib64/libcblas.so.3.8.0
    /usr/lib64/libopenblas-r0.3.12.so
    /usr/lib64/libopenblasp-r0.3.12.so
    ```
    besides,

 3. in `CMakeLists.txt` (CMake version 3.20):
    cmake
    message(STATUS "This is CMake ${CMAKE_VERSION}")
    message(STATUS "")
    set(BLAS_LIBRARIES "/usr/local/lib64/libblas.a")
    set(LAPACK_LIBRARIES "/usr/local/lib64/liblapack.a") 
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} /usr/lib64) 
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.4) # # We support all policy changes up to version 3.11. 
    # cmake_policy(VERSION 3.13.4)
````

4. Moreover, I tried to install SuiteSparse individually. However,I got the same issue with same error information

Could anyone provide a hint or suggestions?

I checked the error information from Cmake error file,I found :

```
Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_14be7/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_14be7.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_14be7.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/var/install/dealii/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_14be7.dir/src.c.o
/usr/bin/cc -DLAPACK_SYMBOL_CHECK   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_14be7.dir/src.c.o -c /var/install/dealii/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c
Linking C executable cmTC_14be7
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_14be7.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc CMakeFiles/cmTC_14be7.dir/src.c.o -o cmTC_14be7  -lm -ldl /usr/local/lib64/libopenblas.a 
/usr/local/lib64/libopenblas.a(blas_server.c.o): In function `openblas_setaffinity':
blas_server.c:(.text+0x34b): undefined reference to `pthread_setaffinity_np'
/usr/local/lib64/libopenblas.a(blas_server.c.o): In function `openblas_getaffinity':
blas_server.c:(.text+0x3cd): undefined reference to `pthread_getaffinity_np'
/usr/local/lib64/libopenblas.a(blas_server.c.o): In function `blas_thread_init':
blas_server.c:(.text+0x896): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/local/lib64/libopenblas.a(blas_server.c.o): In function `goto_set_num_threads':
blas_server.c:(.text+0xf07): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/local/lib64/libopenblas.a(blas_server.c.o): In function `blas_thread_shutdown_':
blas_server.c:(.text+0x12de): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/usr/local/lib64/libopenblas.a(sgesvd.f.o): In function `sgesvd_':
sgesvd.f:(.text+0x436): undefined reference to `_gfortran_concat_string'
sgesvd.f:(.text+0x1294): undefined reference to `_gfortran_concat_string'
/usr/local/lib64/libopenblas.a(shseqr.f.o): In function `shseqr_':
shseqr.f:(.text+0x5c3): undefined reference to `_gfortran_concat_string'
/usr/local/lib64/libopenblas.a(sormbr.f.o): In function `sormbr_':
sormbr.f:(.text+0x35e): undefined reference to `_gfortran_concat_string'
sormbr.f:(.text+0x3fa): undefined reference to `_gfortran_concat_string'
/usr/local/lib64/libopenblas.a(sormbr.f.o):sormbr.f:(.text+0x4a0): more undefined references to `_gfortran_concat_string' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_14be7.dir/build.make:100: cmTC_14be7] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/var/install/dealii/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_14be7/fast] Error 2

Source file was:

      #define MANGLE(name, NAME) name ## _

      char MANGLE(daxpy, DAXPY)(); char MANGLE(dgeev, DGEEV)(); char MANGLE(dgeevx, DGEEVX)(); char MANGLE(dgelsd, DGELSD)();
      char MANGLE(dgemm, DGEMM)(); char MANGLE(dgemv, DGEMV)(); char MANGLE(dgeqrf, DGEQRF)(); char MANGLE(dgesdd, DGESDD)();
      char MANGLE(dgesvd, DGESVD)(); char MANGLE(dgetrf, DGETRF)(); char MANGLE(dgetri, DGETRI)(); char MANGLE(dgetrs, DGETRS)();
      char MANGLE(dorgqr, DORGQR)(); char MANGLE(dormqr, DORMQR)(); char MANGLE(dstev, DSTEV)(); char MANGLE(dsyevx, DSYEVX)();
      char MANGLE(dsygv, DSYGV)(); char MANGLE(dsygvx, DSYGVX)(); char MANGLE(dtrtrs, DTRTRS)(); char MANGLE(saxpy, SAXPY)();
      char MANGLE(sgeev, SGEEV)(); char MANGLE(sgeevx, SGEEVX)(); char MANGLE(sgelsd, SGELSD)(); char MANGLE(sgemm, SGEMM)();
      char MANGLE(sgemv, SGEMV)(); char MANGLE(sgeqrf, SGEQRF)(); char MANGLE(sgesdd, SGESDD)(); char MANGLE(sgesvd, SGESVD)();
      char MANGLE(sgetrf, SGETRF)(); char MANGLE(sgetri, SGETRI)(); char MANGLE(sgetrs, SGETRS)(); char MANGLE(sorgqr, SORGQR)();
      char MANGLE(sormqr, SORMQR)(); char MANGLE(sstev, SSTEV)(); char MANGLE(ssyevx, SSYEVX)(); char MANGLE(ssygv, SSYGV)();
      char MANGLE(ssygvx, SSYGVX)(); char MANGLE(strtrs, STRTRS)();
      int main(){
        MANGLE(daxpy, DAXPY)(); MANGLE(dgeev, DGEEV)(); MANGLE(dgeevx, DGEEVX)(); MANGLE(dgelsd, DGELSD)(); MANGLE(dgemm, DGEMM)();
        MANGLE(dgemv, DGEMV)(); MANGLE(dgeqrf, DGEQRF)(); MANGLE(dgesdd, DGESDD)(); MANGLE(dgesvd, DGESVD)(); MANGLE(dgetrf, DGETRF)();
        MANGLE(dgetri, DGETRI)(); MANGLE(dgetrs, DGETRS)(); MANGLE(dorgqr, DORGQR)(); MANGLE(dormqr, DORMQR)(); MANGLE(dstev, DSTEV)();
        MANGLE(dsyevx, DSYEVX)(); MANGLE(dsygv, DSYGV)(); MANGLE(dsygvx, DSYGVX)(); MANGLE(dtrtrs, DTRTRS)(); MANGLE(saxpy, SAXPY)();
        MANGLE(sgeev, SGEEV)(); MANGLE(sgeevx, SGEEVX)(); MANGLE(sgelsd, SGELSD)(); MANGLE(sgemm, SGEMM)(); MANGLE(sgemv, SGEMV)();
        MANGLE(sgeqrf, SGEQRF)(); MANGLE(sgesdd, SGESDD)(); MANGLE(sgesvd, SGESVD)(); MANGLE(sgetrf, SGETRF)(); MANGLE(sgetri, SGETRI)();
        MANGLE(sgetrs, SGETRS)(); MANGLE(sorgqr, SORGQR)(); MANGLE(sormqr, SORMQR)(); MANGLE(sstev, SSTEV)(); MANGLE(ssyevx, SSYEVX)();
        MANGLE(ssygv, SSYGV)(); MANGLE(ssygvx, SSYGVX)(); MANGLE(strtrs, STRTRS)();

        return 0;
      }
```

Performing C++ SOURCE FILE Test MKL_SYMBOL_CHECK failed with the following output:

```
Change Dir: /var/install/dealii/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_fb356/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_fb356.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_fb356.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/var/install/dealii/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_fb356.dir/src.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++ -DMKL_SYMBOL_CHECK  -std=c++14 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_fb356.dir/src.cxx.o -c /var/install/dealii/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
/var/install/dealii/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:2:14: fatal error: mkl.h: No such file or directory
#include <mkl.h>
              ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_fb356.dir/build.make:78: CMakeFiles/cmTC_fb356.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/var/install/dealii/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_fb356/fast] Error 2
```

from the information above,the libs have been detected,but does the blas not work due to the missing information of Pthread?

```
/usr/bin/cc CMakeFiles/cmTC_14be7.dir/src.c.o -o cmTC_14be7  -lm -ldl /usr/local/lib64/libopenblas.a 
/usr/local/lib64/libopenblas.a(blas_server.c.o): In function `openblas_setaffinity':
blas_server.c:(.text+0x34b): undefined reference to `pthread_setaffinity_np'
```

Comment: "when I installed deal.II..." - I understand that that you get errors when configure deal.II project, which is not written by yours. But then you also provided some `CMakeLists.txt`. How does this `CMakeLists.txt` relate to the problem? Via `-DLAPACK_LIBRARIES` option you passes **static** lapack and blas libraries. But then you also list shared libraries (`/usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3`, etc.). How these **shared** libraries are related to the problem?

Comment: Hi,I wrote these libraries because I want prove that the lappack and blas have been successfully installed.

Comment: `-DLAPACK_FOUND=true` - This is wrong. FOUND variables should never be set as a hint to CMake. Such settings could only confuse the build system. `-DLAPACK_LIBRARIES=...` - this setting is wrong too. This variable should be set by the [FindLAPACK.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindLAPACK.html) script itself. Try to clean build directory and re-run configuration without that settings.

Comment: "I want prove that the lappack and blas have been successfully installed." - According to that list of libraries, you have installed only **runtime** for Lapack and BLAS, but have not installed **development** packages for them. A development package for LAPACK should contain file `liblapack.so` **without** any suffix after the `.so` extension.